# Problem with java array. making it a certain size and let the user input data to the array

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I had a assignment for school but I'm stuck and could use some tips.

The assignment is that I need to make a array and let the user put data in the array by using a scanner and a loop. If the user puts a empty string in the scanner the scanner should stop and should print out the array. Also the array cannot be longer then 25 length.

```
public class invoerOpslaan {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] arrayList = new String[25];
    String input;
    int i = 0;

    for (input = scanner.nextLine(); !input.isEmpty(); input = scanner.nextLine()) {
        arrayList[i] = input;
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(arrayList[]);
}
```

I have my array set to be 25 length but how can I make it so that a user puts in 15 strings in the array that the array will be 15 instead of 25. And if the user puts the 25th string in the array it will automatically stop the scanner and print out the array.

Comment: Are you allowed to use an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Use a `List` if you're allowed to, or else initialize a `String[25]` and then use the `Arrays.copyOf` method.

Comment: Also, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names always start with uppercase.

Comment: change your middle for-loop section to !input.isEmpty() && i < 25

Comment: i'm aloud to use anything aslong as i get the results. and thanks for the tip @MCEmperor will change it right away. also will be looking up more java naming conventions. still really new to this :)

Comment: @CedricSmit [The Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). It isn't really much, so it shouldn't be hard to adapt to them. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not allowed to use a `List` then loop through every element that contains a value in the array and create a new array (with the size of `i`) using all of those elements.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] arrayList = new String[25];
    String input;
    int i = 0;

    for (input = scanner.nextLine(); (!input.isEmpty() && i < 25); input = scanner.nextLine()) {
        arrayList[i] = input;
        i++;
    }

    String[] newArrayList = new String[i];

    int index = 0;
    for (String element : arrayList) {
        if (element == null)
            continue;
        newArrayList[index] = element;
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: what means for (String element : arrayList)  what are you exactly checking here? since i dont understand the --> :

Comment: Sorry for the late response! The `:` symbol represents `in`. The `for` statement loops through every element in the list.

Comment: Ahh. yea i always used the for loop and interate through an array but this is way easier. Thanks for the response tho ! even tho it was  abit late :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ArrayList` to give a dynamic size array to your code.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
String input;
int i = 0;
for (input = scanner.nextLine(); !input.isEmpty(); input = scanner.nextLine()) {
    arrayList.add(input);
    i++;
}
System.out.println(arrayList);
```

And `System.out.println` will give you an output like this:

```
[Hello, World!]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use a `List` you can use [`Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[],%20int)) and `i` to copy as many elements as the user inputted to a new `Array`. Also you don't actually check to make sure `i` is less than 25. Make sure you check in your loop:

```
for (input = scanner.nextLine(); !input.isEmpty() && i < 25; input = scanner.nextLine()) {
    arrayList[i] = input;
    i++;
}
String[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(arrayList, i);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
```